# Wordpress mu table wp_blogs corrupt after MySql upgrade

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mu

i have an old Wordpress Mu (2.8.4) installation running on a hosted webspace. Now my Provider suddenly upgraded PHP and MySQL.

Now my Wordpress Mu installation doesn't work anymore, seems the reason is that the table WP_BLOGS is corrupt.

The error: #1034 - Incorrect key file for table 'wp_blogs';

What are my options now?

I mailed my provider, but i don't expect any real help from him.

I also found this blogposting: http://appsguy.com/2011/07/22/fixing-a-wordpress-mu-redirect-loop/ which isn't an option for me because i don't know which of my 7 blogs on Mu had which id

Comment: What you could try is getting a copy of the database, creating a local install using Xamp, import the database and go through each of the blog options tables ie:
blog_1_wp_options inside this table will be a record called home, this will show you the wp url for that domain or site, then repeat for each others? then on youre current host, create a new wordpress install using the latest version, and start a new multi blog install,  :( Ive also had issues with older versions of mu, with over 50 blogs on it, and it was a nightmare when our host upgraded there php and mysql... good luck..

Comment: Thanks Marty.
But i think restoring the table WP_BLOGS could be sufficient, since all other tables seem to be alright and can be accessed.